# Freenx authentication failure / installation error?

Tags: nx, archbang

I'm trying to setup a server on an ArchBang OS.

I get installation warnings/errors when I try to install FreeNX on an ArchBang OS.
I also get an Authentication error that stops the NX server.
I don't know if the two are related.

Commands entered:

```
sudo pacman -S openssh
sudo sed -i 's/\#PermitRootLogin/PermitRootLogin/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed -i '$a\AllowUsers    folatt' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo systemctl enable sshd.socket
sudo reboot
yaourt -S nx-all
sudo nxserver --status
```

Last command output:

```
NX> 900 Connecting to server ...
NX> 204 Authentication to NX server failed.
NX> 110 NX Server is stopped.
NX> 999 Bye.
```

Second last command output:

```
NX> 723 Cannot start NX statistics:
NX> 709 NX statistics are disabled for this server.
NX> 700 WARNING: Error when trying to connect to NX server, error is:
NX> 700 WARNING: nxsetup cannot validate the sanity of the current installation:
NX> 700 WARNING: the current system or NX configuration could be broken.
NX> 700 WARNING: If difficulties arise (for example sessions cannot be started),
NX> 700 WARNING: it is advisable that you try to uninstall the NX server and the
NX> 700 WARNING: NX client packages then install them again.
NX> 700 WARNING: Search also the NoMachine Knowledge Base at the URL below:
NX> 700 WARNING: http://www.nomachine.com/kb
NX> 700 WARNING: for common errors encountered when performing a software update
NX> 700 WARNING: and the related hints on how to solve them..
NX> 700 Installation of NX server was completed with warnings.
NX> 700 Please review the install log '/usr/NX/var/log/install'
NX> 700 for further details.
NX> 700 Showing file: /usr/NX/share/documents/server/install-notices
```

/usr/NX/var/log/install

```
NX> 700 Starting: install node operation at: Wed May 11 11:14:09 2016.
NX> 700 Autodetected system 'arch'.
NX> 700 Install log is '/usr/NX/var/log/install'.
NX> 700 Creating configuration in /usr/NX/etc/node.cfg.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/cp -f '/usr/NX/etc/node-arch.cfg.sample' '/usr/NX/etc/node.cfg'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Inspecting local CUPS environment.
NX> 700 Generating CUPS entries in: /usr/NX/etc/node.cfg.
NX> 700 Running: ln -sf /usr/NX/bin/nxspool /usr/lib64/cups/backend/nx.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Replacing: /usr/NX/etc/node.cfg.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/cp -f /usr/NX/etc/node.cfg.tmp /usr/NX/etc/node.cfg.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Deleting temporary file.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/rm -f /usr/NX/etc/node.cfg.tmp.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/bin/nxuexec'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 555 '/usr/NX/bin/nxuexec'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/bin/nxuexec'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxkeyadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxkeyadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxkeyadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxtmpperm.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxtmpperm.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxtmpperm.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 CUPS support is disabled.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxuseradd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxuseradd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxuseradd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxuserdel.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxuserdel.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxuserdel.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: /usr/NX/bin/nxnode --validate.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/mv '/usr/NX/etc/node.lic.sample' '/usr/NX/etc/node.lic'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/etc/node.lic'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 0400 '/usr/NX/etc/node.lic'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxlicense.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxlicense.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxlicense.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/tmp/.ICE-unix'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 01777 '/tmp/.ICE-unix'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/tmp/.X11-unix'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 01777 '/tmp/.X11-unix'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxmountadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxmountadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxmountadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxmountdel.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxmountdel.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxmountdel.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Installation of version: 3.5.0-9 completed.
NX> 700 Showing file: /usr/NX/share/documents/node/cups-info
NX> 700 Bye.


NX> 700 Installing: server at: Wed May 11 11:14:11 2016.
NX> 700 Autodetected system: arch.
NX> 700 Install log is: /usr/NX/var/log/install.
NX> 700 Running: useradd -p '*' -d '/usr/NX/home/nx' -r nx.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Command: echo '/usr/NX/bin/nxserver' | /usr/bin/chsh nx.
NX> 700 chsh: Warning: "/usr/NX/bin/nxserver" is not listed in /etc/shells.
Changing shell for nx.
New shell [/bin/bash]: Shell changed..
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: ssh-keygen -q -t dsa -N '' -f '/usr/NX/etc/keys/node.localhost.id_dsa'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/cp -f '/usr/NX/etc/passwords.db.sample' '/usr/NX/etc/passwords.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: touch '/usr/NX/etc/passwords.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/passwords.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/cp -f '/usr/NX/etc/administrators.db.sample' '/usr/NX/etc/administrators.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: touch '/usr/NX/etc/administrators.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/administrators.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/cp -f '/usr/NX/etc/guests.db.sample' '/usr/NX/etc/guests.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: touch '/usr/NX/etc/guests.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/guests.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/cp -f '/usr/NX/etc/profiles.db.sample' '/usr/NX/etc/profiles.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: touch '/usr/NX/etc/profiles.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/profiles.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: touch '/usr/NX/etc/users.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/users.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: touch '/usr/NX/etc/users.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/cp -fp '/usr/NX/home/nx/.ssh/restore.id_dsa.pub' '/usr/NX/home/nx/.ssh/default.id_dsa.pub'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/keys'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/keys/node.localhost.id_dsa'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown -R nx:root '/usr/NX/home/nx'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 0700 '/usr/NX/home/nx'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/var'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/var/db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown -R nx:root '/usr/NX/var/db/closed'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown -R nx:root '/usr/NX/var/db/running'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown -R nx:root '/usr/NX/var/db/failed'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/passwords.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 0600 '/usr/NX/etc/passwords.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/passwords.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/users.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 0600 '/usr/NX/etc/users.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/users.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/guests.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 0600 '/usr/NX/etc/guests.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/guests.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 0600 '/usr/NX/etc/administrators.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/administrators.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/administrators.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 0600 '/usr/NX/etc/profiles.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/profiles.db'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/profiles.db.lock'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: touch /usr/NX/etc/nodes.db.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx /usr/NX/etc/nodes.db.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: touch /usr/NX/etc/nodes.db.lock.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx /usr/NX/etc/nodes.db.lock.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: touch /usr/NX/var/db/broadcast.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx /usr/NX/var/db/broadcast.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Creating configuration file: /usr/NX/etc/server.cfg.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/cp -f '/usr/NX/etc/server-arch.cfg.sample' '/usr/NX/etc/server.cfg'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --validate.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/mv '/usr/NX/etc/server.lic.sample' '/usr/NX/etc/server.lic'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown nx:root '/usr/NX/etc/server.lic'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 0400 '/usr/NX/etc/server.lic'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --validatenode.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown -R nx '/usr/NX/var/db/stat'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod  0770 '/usr/NX/var/db/stat'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/cp -p '/usr/NX/home/nx/.ssh/default.id_dsa.pub' '/usr/NX/home/nx/.ssh/authorized_keys2'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Cannot start NX statistics: NX> 701 NX statistics are disabled for this server.
NX> 700 Running: /bin/mv -f /usr/NX/etc/server.cfg.tmp /usr/NX/etc/server.cfg.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxwtmpadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxwtmpadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxwtmpadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxcookiegen.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxcookiegen.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxcookiegen.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxhost.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxhost.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxhost.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxdpyinfo.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxdpyinfo.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxdpyinfo.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxwtmpdel.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxwtmpdel.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxwtmpdel.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxpasswd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxpasswd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxpasswd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxconfigure.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxconfigure.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxconfigure.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxgroupadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxgroupadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxgroupadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chown root:root '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxquotaadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod 744 '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxquotaadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 Running: chmod u+s '/usr/NX/scripts/restricted/nxquotaadd.sh'.
NX> 700 Result: OK.
NX> 700 WARNING: Error when trying to connect to NX server, error is:
NX> 700 WARNING: nxsetup cannot validate the sanity of the current installation:
NX> 700 WARNING: the current system or NX configuration could be broken.
NX> 700 WARNING: If difficulties arise (for example sessions cannot be started),
NX> 700 WARNING: it is advisable that you try to uninstall the NX server and the
NX> 700 WARNING: NX client packages then install them again.
NX> 700 WARNING: Search also the NoMachine Knowledge Base at the URL below:
NX> 700 WARNING: http://www.nomachine.com/kb
NX> 700 WARNING: for common errors encountered when performing a software update
NX> 700 WARNING: and the related hints on how to solve them..
NX> 700 Installation of NX server was completed with warnings.
NX> 700 Please review the install log '/usr/NX/var/log/install'
NX> 700 for further details.
NX> 700 Showing file: /usr/NX/share/documents/server/install-notices
NX> 700 Bye.
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.98 2016/02/17 05:29:04 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no # pam does that
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
AllowUsers    folatt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nx package is severely outdated and I had to download the source code. Then I chose fedora as the system to install on even though it's an Arch OS.

The put the nxserver up running. I can't connect to it yet though.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and resolved it by adding:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I am not sure if this cause some security isuues or not.